# How can I make moong dal crepe crispy?

Tags: indian-cuisine, texture, batter, pancakes

I'm making a north Indian snack for my toddler, he likes crispy textures.

Moong dal ground with water, added chopped onion and cilantro.

The batter was thin like a crepe batter and cooked in frying pan. The edges were crispy. The interior was like a crepe.

- Would boiling off some water help (adding more water in the beginning helps the grinding process and smooths the moong dal)?
- Would Rice flour help?
- I know America test kitchen adds baking soda to things to increase browning, would that work?

How can I improve the texture to make the outside more crispy?

Answer (score 2):

Just add some semolina and rice flour. This would help a lot to make your crepes crispy